# new to eclipse and c++: how does a c++ project get deployed?

Tags: c++, eclipse

i am using c++ in eclipse, a project which contains many header files , cpp files...etc when finally done, how does it actually get implemented in the real world once it is done? Does an .exe file get created ?  Or how can users   install the program on their computers?

Can you share your experience with me ?

Also can you tell me what IDE you use for C++ development ?

I tried to look through some documentation but could not find anything.

Comment: I use visual studios. If you are a student you can get it for free.

Comment: ok, so how do you do it in visual studio ?

Comment: Generally, on Windows, you build an installer that bundles the .exe file and whatever else using an installer toolkit. Visual Studio bundles an installer toolkit, you can also use NSIS.

Comment: @BridgetCay Search MSDN for "installer"? (Googling for "create installer visual studio" also turns up this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353)

Comment: can you tell me what do you use an installer for ?

Answer (score 0):

When you compile the code, it will output an executable file (.exe) that can then be run from a command line, double-clicked, or put into an installer.  The executable files name will be .exe and placed in the output directory as specified in your project settings.

As mentioned, this can be bundled in an installer but that is very likely overkill and way beyond what you want.  So long as you have used standard C/C++ libraries that come installed on a user's system, they can just invoke the program from a command line or simply double-click the executable.  If your program doesn't have any interface and simply prints messages, then they person will want to run it from the command line.  Finally, if you have used other libraries that you need to include with your program, then an installer may be what you need in order to make sure the end user has everything they need to run your program.

As far as IDE's go, I've used both Eclipse and Visual Studio.  Visual Studio is better tailored to C/C++ development (this is assuming you are programming on a Windows machine) but has the downside of costing money if you don't get it through your employer or school.  If you can get access to it through either of those channels, I would choose it over Eclipse.  Eclipse will do what you want and is free, but Visual Studio might be a bit better.  Also, if you are going to spend money anyway, I suggest looking a SlickEdit.  I use this at work and really like it for C/C++ development.